# How to display date/ time of current user base on time zone?

Tags: 7, datetime

Is it possible to display date/time of current user in his/her profile page. It should be base on his/her time zone settings. How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the user pages (view/edit/etc) with the user templates, like the [user profile template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7.x) In the template's top documentation there's some good info like:

```
 * Use render($user_profile) to print all profile items, or print a subset
 * such as render($user_profile['user_picture']). Always call
 * render($user_profile) at the end in order to print all remaining items.
```

So you can first dpm the $user_profile array and find out the user's timezone, then add php code after the `print render($user_profile);` to print the date/time according to the timezone value you retrieved from the user profile array.